# Access php files through a link on the web

Tags: php, html

I have created a very simple html page. Below is the code of the html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Client Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Sign up.php">
            <table width='400' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='1' align='left' style='margin:186 90' border='0'>          
                <td><font size="3" face="arial, helvetica">Don't have an account? Please register 
                <td><font size="3" face="arial, helvetica"><input type='submit'  name='signup' value='Sign Up'/>
            </table>
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

moreover if i add some php code inside I run it through wamp from an apache server.

I would like to ask you if i want to load this on the internet to a specific URL how can i do it ??
For example, to open my web browser and write at the URL address: http://www.exampleWebSite.com and then my page to show up.

Thank you

Comment: This isn't a programming question. But the gist of it is to 1) get a domain name 2) get web hosting 3) upload your files to hosting

Comment: If you want to show the page,first you should upload it to the server.And make the file name to index.html/index.php.That's the first page server is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In short: **NO** you can not achieve what you'd like to do in the way you suggested.
First off, you'd need to own *said* domain and have hosting for it.

### How to:

1. Purchase a domain name from a [domain registrar (Google search)](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=domain%20regitrars&oq=domain%20regitrars&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2928j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)
2. Purchase hosting for *said* domain (***optionally*** with the domain registrar)
3. Upload files to your hosting.
4. Access your file through your domain (whatever it may be). For example **http://www.myderpydomain.com**

That way you can now run your file (for this example we shall call it **`index.html`**)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Client Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="Sign_up.php">
            <table width='400' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='1' align='left' style='margin:186 90' border='0'>          
                <td><font size="3" face="arial, helvetica">Don't have an account? Please register 
                <td><font size="3" face="arial, helvetica"><input type='submit'  name='signup' value='Sign Up'/>
            </table>
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

and now as you can see, your form action is set to `Sign_up.php`. You need this file to process your form, which I pressume you will write up. But here's a *"placeholder"* script in the mean time.

```
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST)) {
print_r($_POST);
}

?>
```

#### NOTE

I just noticed you have a form to link to your sign-up page. Why not use an **`<a>`** (ANCHOR) element which was designed for this kind of thing.

```
<a href="Sign_up.php">Sign Up Now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  tag or change your form's action attribute to your sample website.

```
<form action="post" method="http://www.example.com">
```

or

not  using a form

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Sign Up</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your html file to your web server. That is not possible.