# How do I publish my PHP, HTML, CSS coded website?

Tags: php, html, css, web, publish

Okay here's the scenario: 
Suppose I'm already done designing and coding a website (in PHP, HTML, CSS and other stuffs that help create a website functional) which is still sitting on my desktop, the question is "What's next? How do I publish it to the web?"

Please help, I've seen some tutorials but couldn't understand them.

Comment: You need to learn about hosting a website

Comment: You Google your question. This is too broad.

Comment: Now purchase a domain and purchase hosting than install ftp on your Desktop  and open ftp than put the details of your wesite ftp account and open the folder and upload your website .

Comment: [Read the **How To Steps** in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23622406/2518525)

Comment: Here: 2 seconds on Google gave me => http://www.wikihow.com/Publish-a-Web-Site-on-Your-Own-Domain amongst many results.

Answer (score 1):

Well, once you got your website, next step is to find a hosting to place it.

Take in mind, if you are going to "free hosting", some of them don't allow PHP files.

Once you got it, I'll reccomend you a FTP client, such FileZilla or similars, to upload your content to the hosting. Make sure, of course you got a page called index.php/index.html, so it will be loaded when you type in your website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about [How to do web hosting](http://www.tizag.com/webhost/index.php)

And so many things like

1. Domain registration
2. Webserver

and so many.You can have a good and simple tutorial for a beginner in the reference link.